# PayPal SOAP API - Version is not supported

Tags: c#, soap, paypal

I use .Net, and Visual Studio 2010.

I downloaded the WSDLs and corrected the [maxOccurs error](https://www.x.com/message/211491#211491), and adding the WSDL as a Web Reference works just fine.

The problem occurs when I call SetExpressCheckout. The error simply says, Version is not supported. I have checked the version of the WSDL, which is 76.0 - and should be correct AFAIK.

The Web Service endpoint being used is this: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/

Is there anywhere I need to specify the version, or is the service endpoint being used wrong?

Comment: Can someone help to answer the following please ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762703/integrating-paypal-in-c-net-solution-using-wsdl-soap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem, you need to specify the version:

```
PayPalAPIAASoapBinding api = new PayPalAPIAASoapBinding();

// Service Provider's API Credentials
api.RequesterCredentials = new CustomSecurityHeaderType();
api.RequesterCredentials.Credentials = new UserIdPasswordType();
api.RequesterCredentials.Credentials.Username = this.Username;
api.RequesterCredentials.Credentials.Password = this.Password;
api.RequesterCredentials.Credentials.Signature = this.ApiSignature;

// The merchant's PayPal e-mail address (3rd party authentication)
api.RequesterCredentials.Credentials.Subject = this.CustomerId;

SetExpressCheckoutReq req = new SetExpressCheckoutReq();
req.SetExpressCheckoutRequest = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
req.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
req.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.Version = "74.0";
```

Right now the Sandbox runs in v 74.0, and production in 76.0. PayPal doesn't always run same versions across their environments.

Comment: Tip: Get the source of any sandbox and/or live PayPal page and find the comment block near the top. That'll show the latest version of the environment you're currently on. (I.e. web version: 76.0-1971782)

Comment: @Robert Thanks, that would be useful when switching back and forth, and after updating the WSDL reference.

Comment: Fixed version error for me.  I guessed there was a version parameter somewhere, but could not get my paws on it.  Thank u!